# Apache mod_proxy_fcgi, php-fpm and url rewriting issue

Tags: php, apache

I need to migrate an app from Apache PHP module to PHP-FPM, for that I saw that mod_proxy_fcgi was the preferred way.

The app is running the old Zend framework 1.

Some relevant parts from the VHost:

```
RewriteEngine on
DocumentRoot /home/app/www
<Directory "/home/app/www">
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
                Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://php7/"
</FilesMatch>
<Proxy fcgi://php7>
    ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=240
</Proxy>
```

My endpoint is http://server/CLIENT/index.php

In /home/app/www/CLIENT/.htaccess I have ([as specified by the Zend Framework 1.0](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.0/en/zend.controller.router.html))

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0 [L]
```

When I hit a standard php page, all goes well. But whenever I want to use the router, I get a 404 provided by PHP-FPM (for example http://server/CLIENT/page). I still can have my router working by directly browsing http://server/CLIENT/index.php/page.

URL rewriting runs since when I enable debug rewriting logs I can see it goes through all the rules.

Interstingly, I also tested PHP-FPM with the old mod_fastcgi. Via this method, all goes well with the exact same configuration. Even more, the debug of the rewrite logs are strictly the same.

I am struggling with that for days now. Is anyone having a brilliant idea to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

While this is probably not the best answer I did have the exact same issue. Rewritting your .htaccess file to have a ? at the end of the index.php did resolve it for me.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?/$0 [L]
```

Note the addition of a question mark on the RewriteRule.

If you resolved it differently update this post.